# What formula is used for finding the velocity of a particle, that is moving around an object with a charge density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, velocity

A particle with a mass $m$, and charge $q$, moving around an infinite wire, where the wire has some charge density, given in $nC/m$. How can I extract the relation of this information, to see how the velocity of the particle is found?

Edit:
The particle moves in a uniform circular motion, in an ideal setting, around the wire.

Comment: How is the particle moving around the wire?  In a circle, like a planet orbiting?  If it is then you can look up the equation for circular motion (the velocity must be just high enough to stop the particle spiralling in or out).

Comment: Also note that a circular motion solution will be artificial because in the real world the particle will radiate energy away and gradually spiral in.  But for a toy example, which I suspect this is, you might not have to consider such complexities.

Comment: Yes, toy example. If it moves in a circular motion, like a perfect orbit, the formula would be $a=v^2/r$. Maybe I could find the radius of the wire, by using the charge density, derive it from that. But wouldn't I still need to know the acceleration?

Comment: $a = v^2 / r$ is one acceleration, and it exactly cancels out another one, which is the acceleration due to the mutual attraction of $q$ and the charge density in the wire (if the charge q and the charge density in the wire have the same sign then the particle will just spiral away).  Coulomb's law is probably useful to you.

Comment: Have you already worked out the electric field $\vec{E}(\vec{x})$ generated by the charged wire? Once you have done this, it is straightforward to write down the equation of motion of the particle ($m d^2 \vec{x}(t)/dt^2 = q \vec{E}(\vec{x}(t))$ for a nonrelativistic particle and neglecting radiation loss).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say the particle is at a distance $r$ from the wire and let the line charge density (assuming an ideal thin wire) be $\lambda$. For uniform circular motion, we must have the centripetal force on the particle in equilibrium with the electrostatic force on it due to the wire. In other words,
$$
F_c =  F_e \implies \frac{mv^2}{r} = \frac{q\lambda}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 r},
$$
where, $\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 r}$ is the electric field due to a long thin wire with charge density $\lambda$ at a distance $r$. This can be easily derived using Gauss's Law or directly via Coulomb's Law if you please. Thus, the required speed is,
$$
v = \sqrt{\frac{q\lambda}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 m}},
$$
which as expected, is a constant.

Comment: This formula gives a correct, so I marked it as correct. I need to figure out why this is the case though.

Comment: @user6076 the idea is this. For the particle to undergo uniform circular motion under the influence of an electrostatic force, the centripetal force acting on the particle must be due to the electric field of the wire. For a long and thin wire, one can determine the electric field at any given point using Gauss's law (consider a cylindrical gaussian surface). In our case, the surface must be at a radial distance $r$.